# Do serverless functions get dedicated CPU resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I was telling a friend that an advantage of running a load with a lambda function is that each instance, and thus each execution, gets dedicated resources - memory and CPU (and perhaps disk, network,... but that's less relevant). And then I started wondering...

For instance, if you have a function with some CPU-intensive logic that is used by multiple tenants, then one execution should never be affected by another. If some calculation takes 5 seconds to execute, it will *always* take 5 seconds, no matter how many requests are processed simultaneously.

This seems self-evident for memory, but less so for CPU. From a quick test I seem to get mixed results.

So, does every function instance gets its own CPU dedicated resources?

My main focus is AWS Lambda, but the same question arises for Azure (on a Consumption plan, I guess) and Google.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda uses fractional CPU allocations of instance CPU, running on an instance type comparable to [compute optimized EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compute-optimized-instances.html). That CPU share is dedicated to the Lambda, and its allocation is based on the [amount of memory allocated to the function](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=614558).

> The CPU share dedicated to a function is based off of the fraction of
>   its allocated memory, per each of the two cores. For example, an
>   instance with ~ 3 GB memory available for lambda functions where each
>   function can have up to 1 GB memory means at most you can utilize ~
>   1/3 * 2 cores = 2/3 of the CPU. The details may be revisited in the
>   future

The explanation is supported by [Lambda Function Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) documentation, which states:

> Performance testing your Lambda function is a crucial part in ensuring
>   you pick the optimum memory size configuration. **Any increase in memory
>   size triggers an equivalent increase in CPU availabile to your
>   function.**

So yes, you get a dedicated *share* of an instances' total CPU, based on your memory allocation and the formula above.

Comment: does this mean that configuring the lambda with more memory makes it faster at startup- and at runtime?

Comment: In general, yes. But YMMV See https://blog.symphonia.io/the-occasional-chaos-of-aws-lambda-runtime-performance-880773620a7e
Disk and network IO is also proportional to memory allocation, according to that blog.

Comment: I just found [these numbers](http://theburningmonk.com/2017/06/aws-lambda-compare-coldstart-time-with-different-languages-memory-and-code-sizes/) - they suggest that startup time in python and node are not dependent on memory size

Comment: @hansaplast The bootup time is also dependent on the code itself. If you require lots of other modules and/or you have lots of logic that happens at module import time (instead of invocation time), then the memory/CPU will factor in.

Answer (score 1):

It might have been indicated more clearly that I wasn't looking for documentation, but for facts. The core question was if we can assume that *one execution should never be affected by another*.

As I said, a first quick test gave me mixed results, so I took the time to delve in a little deeper.
I created a very simple lambda that, for a specified number of seconds, generates and sums up random numbers (code [here](https://github.com/FreeWillaert/sls-simple-perf-test/blob/11a4af973e8d4f2808a70a01950d112fda95de8e/doit-aws-nodejs/handler.ts#L20-L24)):

```
while (process.hrtime(start)[0] < duration) {
  var nextRandom = randomizer();
  random = random + nextRandom - 0.5;
  rounds++;
}
```

Now, if executions on different instances are really independent, then there should be no difference between executing this lambda just once or multiple times in parallel, all other factors being equal.

But the figures indicate otherwise. Here's a graph, showing the number of 'rounds' per second that was achieved.

[image: 'Rounds' per second with 128MB lambda]

Every datapoint is the average of 10 iterations with the same number of parallel requests - which should rule out cold start effects and other variations. The raw results can be found [here](https://github.com/FreeWillaert/sls-simple-perf-test/blob/master/output_aws_nodejs_128-512.csv).

The results look rather shocking: they indicate that avoiding parallel executions of the same lambda can almost double the performance....?!

But sticking to the original question: this looks like the CPU fraction 'dedicated' to a lambda instance is not fixed, but depends on certain other factors.

Of course I welcome any remarks on the test, and of course, explanations for the observed behavior!